# How do we get the test cases for Google's CodeJam (of archived competitions of course)? - they do not appear on practice mode

Tags: python

I am solving some question on `Google's Codejam 2021 contest`, and am getting wrong answers for one of the questions, but I can't seem to find the test cases they are running? Any ideas where I can get this?

-> There is a mention of not looking at the test cases until you have really tried the problem to the fullest potential- which is what leads me to believe that they exist somewhere.

Here is the link to the contest: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000043580a

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After ending Google's Codejam 2021 contest, we can solve problem in practice mode.
But
they did not provide hidden test case(after competition also)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31447659)